# work envelope volume calculation using reach and stroke values

Tags: mobile-robot

What is the volume of the work envelope of a Cartesian
robot whose x,y,z axes each have maximum reach 1.2m
and maximum stroke 80cm?

current thinking is V= lxbxh as Cartesian.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that's exactly right.  The envelope is the maximum space it can reach and move within (i.e. the volume encompassed).

- The x-axis can move from -1.2m to +1.2m, covering a distance of 2.4m.
- The y-axis can move from -1.2m to +1.2m, covering a distance of 2.4m.
- The z-axis can move from 0m to 0.8m, covering a distance of 0.8m.

So the total envelope is 2.4m x 2.4m x 0.8m = 4.608 cubic meters.